How to exclude subfolders from added local non-maven sources in a Maven project?
I have a Maven project where I have added local non-maven sources(folders). I need to exclude certain subfolders in those sources.
In IntelliJ I can add/exclude accordingly in Project Structure/Modules, but it's not a viable solution as it get reset whenever the project is e.g. reloaded. I got an .iml file where sources are added/excluded, but it's being ignored/overwritten by Maven(I assume).
The folder structure with regards to the project and the sources looks something like this:

Project path: alpha/beta/project

Sources path: alpha/charlie/addedsource

Exclude path: alpha/charlie/addedsource/excludedfolder


I've added the sources using the 'build-helper-maven-plugin' like this:
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>add-source</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>add-source</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <sources>
                            <source>../../charlie/delta</source>
                        </sources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

The issue is excluding the subfolders, or in the example above "alpha/charlie/addedsource/excludedfolder". My understanding is that it's not possible to exclude in 'build-helper-maven-plugin'. Is there another plugin or way to achieve what I'm trying to do in Maven?

Why are those directories needed? What is their purpose? Generated sources should be done in target directory and not in root location or in src location...

The source code for the project are split into multiple sources, and some of the sources are shared with other projects. But some of the sources also contains some duplicated code / dependencies or something like that, which I think is the reason for the exclusions. This is a "the old ways meets the new ways" type of situation that I've been thrown into where, I think, things have been sort of hacked together in order for it to work. It doesn't quite work anymore though.

Separate sources should be done in multiple modules not in a single one ... make separate modules of it..
